# Multiselect segmentedControl

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

How can I build a multi-selectable segmented control like Apple's pages uses to choose the font style (eg Bold, Italic or Underlined)?

Is the segmented control the correct way or is there a better one?

Thanks,
Mica

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is just use a toggle button for each property. You should use [UISwitch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this.

If you don't want to use a UISwitch and prefer a more traditional approach to a toggle button, have a look at [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314299/iphone-toggle-button-implementation). I don't think a segmented control is the way to go at all. The segmented control only has one selected state and it would go against apple's UI guidelines to use it for multiple selected states.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does this very thing in the Xcode GUI; note the multi-select segmented control in the upper right for View. Here's a link for OSX, that might get you closer to an iOS solution

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSegmentedCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSSegmentSwitchTrackingSelectAny

See the value NSSegmentSwitchTrackingSelectAny